# Changing font-size of elements using map, list and for loop in sass

Tags: html, css, for-loop, sass

I have to get values from map to list and then change font-size of h1, h2, h3 using values from list in for loop. My code looks like this:

```
$font-sizes: (
  fs1: 100px,
  fs2: 50px,
  fs3: 6px
);

$list-of-font-sizes: map-values($font-sizes);

@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  h#{$i} {
    @each $size in $list-of-font-sizes {
      font-size: $size;
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why. I've tried also like this:

```
@each $size in $list-of-font-sizes {
  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    h#{$i} {
      font-size: $size;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@for` loop.
Then, you use its index through `nth` to get each size.

```
@for $i from 1 through length($list-of-font-sizes) {
  h#{$i} {
    font-size: nth($list-of-font-sizes, $i);
  }
}
```